# Responsive images (Slick Slider + SlideToggle)

Tags: jquery, css, responsive, slidetoggle

I have a slick slider filled with responsive background images I want to work smoothly with slideToggle.

How do I make that first click smooth without adding a height to .slider
 [image: i.imgur.com/4DLO0Nf.gif]

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="show-slider">Show Slider</button>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="addressBox"> <!-- Slide -->
    <div class="pbottom"></div>
    <div class="artwork" style="background-image: url('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w640/u7ZpBy8eR50ixjumnkQnCUEbpRa.jpg');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="addressBox"> <!-- Slide -->
    <div class="pbottom"></div>
    <div class="artwork" style="background-image: url('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w640/u7ZpBy8eR50ixjumnkQnCUEbpRa.jpg');"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="addressBox"> <!-- Slide -->
    <div class="pbottom"></div>
    <div class="artwork" style="background-image: url('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w640/u7ZpBy8eR50ixjumnkQnCUEbpRa.jpg');"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var $slider = $('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});

$('.show-slider').on("click", function() {
  $slider.slideToggle().get(0).slick.setPosition();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.slider {
  display: none;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  height: auto;
}

.pbottom {
  padding: 73.125% 0;
}

.artwork {
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/9zhd87yv/

Comment: looks ok to me... shouldn't you be using slidesToShow:1 and slidesToScroll: 1 ?

Comment: @Jake, could you please ask a question? Or, at least, state in clear what is the desired behavior? You probably think "*I have a slick slider filled with responsive background images I want to work smoothly with slideToggle*" is clear to everyone, but, in fact, it's really not.

Comment: No, I want it to show 3 slides. @Andrei Gheorghiu the first time you click the button it adds height 1px and is not smooth. But, after that first click, it all appears to work. The question is: How do I make that first click smooth without adding a height to .slider see gif http://i.imgur.com/4DLO0Nf.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9zhd87yv/1/

I had to remove the padding from `.arbtbox`, do some more adjusting and add `position:relative` to `.addressBox`.

```
.addressBox {
   position: relative;
}
```

I changed a few more things in it. Don't remember all. I was just trying to make it look better. Feel free to look at differences side-by-side.

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thank you so much, Andrei.